# Query with custom taxonomy not working

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query-posts

I have custom post type '**mix**'. And custom taxonomy '**meal**'. And categories in custom taxonomy (one of that is with slug: **breakfast**)

*I have problems with  making query. My code is :*

```
            $args       = array(
                'post_type'         => 'mix',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'meal',
                        'field' => 'breakfast'
                    )
                ),
                'posts_per_page'    => 50
            );
            $query      = new WP_Query( $args );
```

*My loop is:*

```
           if( $query->have_posts() ):
                while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
                     //something here...
                endwhile;
           endif;
```

But problem is that nothing show up.

Comment: You said your taxonomy is 'obrok', but then in your query $args, you have `'taxonomy' => 'meal'`

Which is it?

Comment: @frogg3862 my bad, i change post, see now, still not working

Comment: Try this:
    'taxonomy' => 'meal',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => 'breakfast',

Comment: @frogg3862 It works! But can you explane me why field is slug?

Comment: So the taxonomy and terms are obvious, but why does field have to be slug?

When you add taxonomy parameters, you can specify what 'breakfast' is-- via the `field`. It could be the term's ID, the full name, or slug. See the Codex: 

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: @frogg3862 can you see my other post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225278/permalink-custom-post-type-and-custom-taxonomy

Comment: @frogg3862 as an answer please. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use:

```
'taxonomy' => 'meal', 
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => 'breakfast'
```

The `taxonomy` and `terms` are obvious, but why does field have to be slug? When you add taxonomy parameters, you can specify what 'breakfast' is-- via the field. It could be the term's ID, the full name, or slug. See the codex on [Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)